# Кто работал с imgAreaSelect ? нужна помощь

Tags: jquery

При вставке изображения в модальное окно и выборе области, появляются блоки с классом `imgareaselect-outer` и перекрывают кнопку в модальном окне. Никак не получается их спрятать за кнопкой и модальным окном. Как можно решить эту проблему.

Comment: Используйте css z-index

Comment: я использовал и z-index и создавал родительский тег с overflow hidden и кучу других попыток, даже делал клоны этих блоков заключая их в родительский тег, или эти блоки исчезают или накрывают кнопку((((